# Is $\mathbb Q_r$ algebraically isomorphic to $\mathbb Q_s$ while r and s denote different primes?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

It is obvious that $\mathbb{Q}_r$ is topologically isomorphic to $\mathbb Q_s$ while $r$ and $s$ denote different primes. But I really don't know whether it is true in the aspect of algebra. As I failed to prove it, I think that it is false, but I can't give a counterexample.

Last I'm quite sorry that I'm new to MathJax and I don't know how to use it properly.Thanks for reading and I would appreciate it if you could solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraically"? As rings? groups? vector spaces?

Comment: eh...It is a field.

Comment: Notice that if $p$ is another prime (so that $p$, $r$, $s$ are all different and say different from $2$) then $\mathbb{Q}_r$ contains $\sqrt{p}$ iff $p$ is a square mod $r$. And for any $p$ you can find $r$ and $s$ such that $(p/r)=1$ and $(p/s)=-1$.

Comment: Q3 is not isomorphic to Q5, for the following reason: any field isomorphism would have to map −1 to −1; but Q5 contains a square root of −1, whereas Q3 does not.Thanks to Martin Bright.

Comment: In fact, by Dirichlet's theorem (about primes in arithmetic sequences), for any $r$, $s$ you can find a prime $p$ such that $(p/r)=1$, $(p/s)=-1$ ($(./.)$ is the Legendre symbol). So it proves that all $\mathbb{Q}_r$'s are non-isomorphic as fields.

Comment: same question was posted in mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84142/is-q-r-algebraically-isomorphic-to-q-s-while-r-and-s-denote-different-primes

Comment: And why are they topologically isomorphic? The metric thus defined are "different" in the sense that the topology they determined are distinct, is it not true?

Comment: Various answers are given (in an answer *stricto sensu*, and in the comments) in the MO version of the question, whose [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84142/is-q-r-algebraically-isomorphic-to-q-s-while-r-and-s-denote-different-primes) has been given by @Paul.

Comment: Please define in the question the meaning of $Q_p$. This helps not only the reader, but the software platform, which has no tools to search based on mathematical notation.

Answer (score 35):

Never. Looking at the number of roots of unity in your field suffices to distinguish all ${\mathbb{Q}}_p$ for *odd* values of $p$, because the number of roots of $1$ there is precisely $p-1$. It's different for the $2$-adic numbers, since they have two roots of unity, same as the $3$-adics. But the $2$-adics have a square root of $-7$ and the $3$-adics don't, whereas the $3$-adics have a square root of $10$ and the $2$-adics don't.