# Proof of $\mathbb{Q}_{p} \not\simeq \mathbb{Q}_{q}$ for $p\neq q$ - proof verification

Tags: proof-verification, p-adic-number-theory

I want to know whether my proof of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}\not\simeq \mathbb{Q}_{q}$ for $p\neq q$ primes is right or not. (I know that this question is already asked several times on MSE)

---

We can assume $q\neq 2$. 
We will try to find an integer $m$ such that $p\nmid m$ and $\left(\frac{mp}{q}\right) = 1$. (Legendre symbol). Then $mp$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_{q}$, but it is not in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ since the valuation is 1, which is odd.

If $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = 1$, then we can just set $m = 1$. 
If not, first choose $m'\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\left(\frac{m'}{q}\right) = -1$. (Such $m$ exists since $q>2$). 
Then at least one of $m'$ and $m' + q$ is not a multiple of $p$, and choose $m$ as that one. 
Then 
$$
\left( \frac{mp}{q} \right) = \left( \frac{m}{q}\right)\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = \left( \frac{m'}{q}\right)\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = (-1)(-1) = 1, 
$$
so we are done. I think this proof works when $p =2$.

Comment: Yes, there are several [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93633/is-mathbb-q-r-algebraically-isomorphic-to-mathbb-q-s-while-r-and-s-denote) and also answers at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84142/is-q-r-algebraically-isomorphic-to-q-s-while-r-and-s-denote-different-primes). The comment by user8268 is exactly with Legendre symbols, but you need Dirichlet's theorem. Compare your proof with it!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm slightly confusing - do I need Dirichlet's theorem in my proof? I think my proof is almost the same as user8268's comment, but I can't figure out which step do I have to use Dirichlet's theorem in my proof.